# Pandas: To find duplicate columns

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with different `dtypes` like int, float, object, datatime etc. I am performing `data cleaning`, to list or find duplicate column names in the dataframe.
Duplicate criteria as below:

1. same column names or
2. columns having same data values

I tried using transpose approach `df.T.duplicated()` to list duplicate column names, But seems slow for big dataframe.

I come to know we can use `pivot` or `pivot_table` or `corr` to list duplicate column names.

Can someone explain how to use and interpret it Or Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list duplicate columns by name in a Pandas DataFrame, you can call the [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method on the `.columns` property:

`df.columns.duplicated()`

This should be rather fast, unless you have an enormous number of columns in your data.

Finding duplicate columns by values is a bit tricky, and definitely slower. I wouldn't use any of `pivot`, `pivot_table` or `corr`, as they are slow as well for large data sets. Of the three, `corr` would be the most straightforward to detect duplicate columns - two identical columns would have a correlation of one.

I've found this StackOverflow question to contain some ideas, and I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32961145/15052008) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Stefan, Thanks for detail explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guess 2 columns are having same values, try:

df['column1'].equals(df['column2'])